# Remove values after point

Tags: xslt

I want to Remove the zeros or any other values after point(eg 12.000000000000).
I am using xslt code .my code is like

```
<xsl:if test="value!= ''">
 <tr>
 <td>
 value
 </td>
 <td>
 <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </xsl:if>
```

how can I achive this?

Comment: You should use the `format-number` XSLT function (can't provide a tested example, therefore not answering).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use Number formatting as:
<xsl:if test="value!= ''">
 <tr>
  <td>
    value
  </td>
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(value,'0')"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format-number function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(value,'#')"/>
```

Refer to:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#format-number

Comment: Thanks  Peter... But Peter if I have a value like 0.000000 then it will remove the zero before the point also. by using (value,'0') it was solved..

Comment: Hello Arun, thank you for that update. I was not aware of that. Good to know - thanks! Peter

Answer (score 0):

**Just use**:

```
substring-before(concat(value, '.'), '.')
```

This works for any value -- not just a number. The result is correct even if `value` doesn't contain any dot character.